# Retag R questions misstaged with [tag:dataframes]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes) tag wiki says:

> For data.frame in R, use [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame).

There are currently [794 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+dataframes) that are tagged with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes). I propose to retag them with [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame).

Comment: Unfortunately there are currently 1,881 questions tagged [`dataframes`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes), and we don't have a tool to mass retag just the ones that are also tagged `r`. This will have to be a manual effort.

Comment: Most of the [dataframes] questions are also [pandas].  Should we make these [panda-dataframes] and [r-data.frame]?  (That's a question, not a proposal: I'm familiar with neither [pandas] nor [r].)

Comment: @BilltheLizard: So what's the correct way of proceeding here? Do I retag 20 questions a day for the foreseeable future? Is it worth it or do I just waste my time that way? I have started with a few posts and most of them can be improved in other ways. But so can most new posts.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately chipping away at it is the only way I know to fix a problem like this.

Comment: I've chipped a few off and tidied them up at the same time.

Comment: Down to zero for now, after a lot of work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Task accomplished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+dataframes+-pandas+-python). All [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes) (when combined with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)) were re-tagged (or the tag was removed).

The issue is also been discussed in [this post from earlier today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318933/warn-r-users-from-adding-dataframes-tag-instead-of-data-frame-tag) regarding on how to prevent this queue from growing again in the future.