# How can we distinguish data.table and datatable questions in R?

Tags: discussion

Unfortunately, we have two separate functions/packages in R which share the name "data table" — first, there is [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table) (3600 questions), the 4th-most popular package nested under [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r); second there, is [dt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dt) (79 questions, but increasingly common in the past couple weeks/months — I suspect there are a lot of un-tagged `DT` questions as well).

`DT` stands for `DataTables` as the package "provides an interface to the JavaScript library DataTables". `DT` is primarily used in [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny) applications, making it closely tied (the author of `DT`, Yihui Xie, is also an author of `shiny`) to the *5th*-most popular package under [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r). `DT` also has a function `datatable` which further adds to the confusion.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35364936/3576984) recent question exemplifies the troubles — at a glance, someone could easily be forgiven for thinking the question was `data.table`-related (and in fact, I completed my own answer before realizing I had mis-read). More importantly, from a novice (i.e., someone who is not intimately familiar with all the different functions/packages available) question asker's  point of view, it makes perfect sense to assign the [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table) tag when their question involves the `datatable` function (if you view the edit history of the question, you'll note that the asker tagged the question correctly, but an editor mistakenly replaced [dt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dt) with [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table) before this was ultimately corrected by other editors).

Is there anything we can do as *cognoscenti* to try and obviate these sorts of misunderstandings? I've already edited the tag info for both to try and include a blurb directing users to the correct tags.

Comment: I'm not so sure that this is an appropriate question for Meta Stack Overflow, but rather the main site (rare case, usually it's vice versa).

Comment: R is a great language. Especially with a few functions like, [`plot3D`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/plot3D), [`plot3D`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plot3D/docs/plot3D) and [`plot3d`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgl/docs/plot3d). *Not at all confusing* :-)

Comment: I'm also curious if there's a better way to handle it, but if not, it's not a big problem. The user who added the tag knows better now, I guess; and it took me a only a few seconds to fix it. I don't run into this mistag often. Instead, it's more of [tag:data.frame] vs [tag:dataframes] ( see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287681/1191259 ) and OPs adding tags to draw unmerited attention.

Comment: [`[bootstrap]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309933), anyone?