# Why was the dataframe tag badge awarded another time?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-badges

Around eight hours ago, everyone that had previously earned a *dataframe* badge was awarded it again. 
This seems to be true for each of the [bronze](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5915/dataframe), [silver](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5913/dataframe) and [gold](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5911/dataframe) badges.

I had the bronze badge; I still have one only. The new badge has simply replaced the old one for me, with today's date given as the date it was first earned.

I can't see whether any information about when the badge was originally earned is still available. It's possible that the order of who-earned-it-first has been lost.

What happened here and is it reversible? Is this unique to this particular tag and might it happen again with other badges?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319591/3933332

Comment: That could well explain why this happened, thanks. It's still not clear to me whether it was the intention to re-award all of the badges in this way and potentially lose the order that they were awarded in. Now I know the likely cause, maybe there's an answer on meta that addresses this...

Comment: Well *A new tag dataframe has been created* so, there was a short time this tag didn't existed. Means there also can't be any badges for it

Comment: Ah, I just re-read that sentence. I guess that answers the question then!

Comment: I wonder if this should be answered/closed as dupe/as not reproducible?

Comment: I'm happy for the question to be closed if nobody posts an answer. The linked page doesn't explicitly mention tag badges (though the topic is briefly discussed in the comments section), but after reading it, it is obvious what has happened here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is now [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

---

What actually happened is that you had a bronze badge for the former [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes) tag, and now you have one for [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) tag instead. Note the difference in the **s** at the end. That happened because [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes) is now a synonym while [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) is the main tag. See below for additional info.

---

**Some background**

We, the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) users, had a long term problem with the former [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes) tag being added to [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag questions by a lot of users instead the R specific [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame). [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes) was a general tag with no wiki and no one really knew what this tag stands for. While we had our own [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame) with a good wiki which was supposed to be added to R-data.frame specific questions.

The situation escalated when we reached [2K mistagged questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287681/retag-r-questions-misstaged-with-tagdataframes/) which were almost impossible to retag. [I've posted a Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318933/warn-r-users-from-adding-dataframes-tag-instead-of-data-frame-tag) a year later in a desperate attempt to somehow stop the endless flood of misstaged questions. The community decided to help and we eventually [cleared the huge query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318978/3001626).

But the problem wasn't solved long term and mistagged questions [kept piling up daily](https://gist.github.com/Bhargav-Rao/3a1732dcf0bf4fc6e17d).

We hence (after consulting @Shog9), decided to offer a different solution - a permanent one. We (joined forces from the [GMTs](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/75819/gmts) and [Python](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python) chat rooms) formulated a question [and posted a new Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319590/one-frame-to-rule-them-all-how-to-handle-data-frame-dataframes-mistagging) while almost simultaneously [posting our preferred solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319591/3001626) in order to get feedback from the community.

The proposal was well received and (again, with @Shog9s help) we did the following (copying/pasting from that answer):

---

**The Result**

1. A new tag [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) has been created which has the following tags as its synonyms

   1.1. [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame)

   1.2. [data-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-frame)

   1.3. [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes)
2. A tag-wiki was created to describe the most common languages associated with this tag

   2.1 [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)

   2.2 [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)

   2.3 [apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark)

As a result, all the questions that were previously tagged with either [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame) or [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes) were automatically reatagged with [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) to rule them all.

Comment: This is complete and utterly madness... I will see you again in 6 months crying for it to be reversed, when you get flooded by python questions.

Comment: @Braiam How so? Are you assuming Python users will tag question by both `python` and `r` tags because of this `dataframe` tag? I'm not following your logic, sorry.

Comment: I can’t follow. The problem was that the old tag was used for different purposes, including `r` questions and it was solved by creating a new tag explicitly intended to be used for different purposes, including `r` questions? That sounds pragmatic in that there won’t be mistagged questions anymore, but I don’t understand why this required a new tag with the trailing `s` removed. Just declaring `[r] [dataframes]` a valid combination had exactly the same effect…

Comment: @Holger [dataframes] is used in python, [dataframe] in r and spark. We held a lot of discussion in both the Python chat room and the R chat room to zero in on [dataframe]. This is in sync with other structures like [list], [set], etc. As an aside, Check this [tweet](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105) :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg if you favorite or answer questions with [tag:dataframe], the system will [add those questions to your home page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69085/213575). If you favorite [tag:dataframe], when using `intags:mine` it will present you [all the questions tagged with dataframes, irrespectively if you are a python, r or spark guy.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/f8eIQ.png)

Comment: @Braiam `dataframe` is not language specific. Just like `regex`. If anyone follows this tag, it means that they are willing to answer *any* `dataframe` related questions no matter in what language- just like the `regex` guys do. I specifically, don't follow my home page, rather [I look for specific tags combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r%20dataframe?mode=all). And if we already at it - I wanted to learn Python for long time anyway, so it's a good time to start I guess.

Comment: @DavidArenburg "dataframe is not language specific" for some reason, both have different syntax... I checked http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html. That you know how to do an operation in X language doesn't mean that you are an expert on every language.

Comment: @Braiam OK, maybe [tag:regex] is bad example. What I meant "*dataframe is not language specific*" is that it isn't a language specific *data structure*. A better example for such are [tag:arrays] and [tag:vector] tags probably.